# Is it possible to connect an external Monitor to an Apple Thunderbolt Display?

Tags: external-display, thunderbolt

Well the title says it all but still.

Is there a way to connect an external monitor using a DVI->MiniDP converter to the Thunderbolt Port on the Apple Thunderbolt Display?

Comment: Hmm.  I think DisplayPort 1.2 daisy chaining only supports native DisplayPort or active adapters, but I'm not actually sure, sorry.  (The Thunderbolt display is the only DisplayPort 1.2 compliant monitor in existence that I know of right now, so...)

Answer (score 0):

Chain of two Thunderbolt displays works (eliminating the DVI-MiniDP adapter).

Chain using Apple's DVI->MiniDP adapter and some Dell's monitor doesn't work. 
(So to use 2 monitors I connect them both to MacBook Pro directly)

Comment: is this an answer? Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.